# How to get the current URL in http.go?

Tags: go

I'm using `http.NewRequest` to make several http requests ( obviously ). Now I need to make request and extract some query strings  from the final URL ( there is a redirect ) .

So the question is how can I find the URL (if the final URL if the client  was redirected ) ? There is no such field in [Response](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response).

Please note that I don't need to stop the redirect... only to find what's the URL after request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a callback to `http.Client.CheckRedirect`

```
    // CheckRedirect specifies the policy for handling redirects.
    // If CheckRedirect is not nil, the client calls it before
    // following an HTTP redirect. The arguments req and via are
    // the upcoming request and the requests made already, oldest
    // first. If CheckRedirect returns an error, the Client's Get
    // method returns both the previous Response and
    // CheckRedirect's error (wrapped in a url.Error) instead of
    // issuing the Request req.
    //
    // If CheckRedirect is nil, the Client uses its default policy,
    // which is to stop after 10 consecutive requests.
    CheckRedirect func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
```

You can then inspect the new Request as they happen. Just be sure to institute some sort of limit to prevent redirect loops (as stated in the docs, the default aborts after 10).

Comment: I'm not sure I get how the callback is supposed to work. Is there any material that I can read ? Do I need to call Client.Do in a loop ? Sorry for the silly question but I'm new to programming too.

Comment: ok.. I got it ... i  copied and tweaked the defaultCheckRedirect function .. GO is awesome ! still would be great to find how those callbacks actually work.. right now I see it as magic !

Comment: read everything in the `CheckRedirect` comment string carefully (go documentation is usually very precise, and doesn't repeat itself). There's nothing magic about the callback, it's just a function that's called whenever the client needs to follow a redirect. If you want to get data out of it, use a closure. And don't be afraid to read the source! (which it seems you've figure out)

Answer (score 3):

Although @JimB actually answered the question I'm posting this as it may help someone. I've used an anonymous function. Perhaps could be done better using a closures  but I didn't figured it out yet how closures actually work.

```
req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
cl := http.Client{}
var lastUrlQuery string
cl.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {

    if len(via) > 10 {
        return errors.New("too many redirects")
    }
    lastUrlQuery = req.URL.RequestURI()
    return nil
}
resp, err := cl.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("last url query is %v", lastUrlQuery)
```

Comment: The fact that `lastUrlQuery` is defined outside of your anonymous function and that you can still assign to it makes it a closure :) A closure is just an anonymous function that has access to the scope it was written in i.e. it has lexical scope. Hope that helps.

Comment: @tomwilde thanks! It's just the go tutorial which confuses me ( http://tour.golang.org/#45 ) The example is quite different

Comment: It's the same concept as with `sum`. The added complexity in the tutorial is that the  function is returned from a function instead of declared inline.