# Too many redirects, but through what route?

Tags: redirect, go

I've got a simple web scraper/spider based on goquery, which in turn uses net/http. It works great, until I hit a website with too many redirects.

> Get http://www.example.com/some/path.html: stopped after 10 redirects

But why? Did it redirect to itself? Did it throw me into some spider jail? I want to know to what url's I got redirected, and in what order.

The function giving the error seems to know this, since it's checking the length of a slice of requests, but I don't really want to edit the net/http package myself.

Here's that function from http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go

```
func defaultCheckRedirect(req *Request, via []*Request) error {
    if len(via) >= 10 {
        return errors.New("stopped after 10 redirects")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current URL in http.go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518945/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-http-go)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your own function to `http.Client`, for example:

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *Request, via []*Request) error {
        log.Println("redirect", req.URL)
        if len(via) >= 10 {
            return errors.New("stopped after 10 redirects")
        }
        return nil
    },
}
```