# How to get the URL in Go

Tags: go

I tried looking it up, but couldn't find an already answered question.

How do I get the host part of the URL in Go?

For eg.

if the user enters http://localhost:8080 in the address bar, I wanted to extract "localhost" from the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about extracting the host from a `*http.Request` you can do the following:

`func ExampleHander(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    host := r.Host // This is your host (and will include port if specified)
}`

If you just want to access the host part without the port part you can do the following:

`func ExampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    host, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(r.Host)
}`

For the last one to work you also have to import `net`

Go has wonderful documentation, I would also recommend taking a look at that: [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

Answer (score 1):

Go has built in library that can do it for you.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "net"
import "net/url"
func main() {
    s := "http://localhost:8080"

    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(u.Host)
    fmt.Println(host)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#

Comment: In the example above, how do I get the current URL entered by the user to access the page?

Comment: This depends on how you wrote your server. 
But probably this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519179/170961